# Как проверить что тип является function?

Tags: javascript

```js
// Чтобы узнать тип встроенного объекта используется одалживание метода через toString;
//(работает только если объект встроенный)
var toString = {}.toString;
var arr = [];
console.log(toString.call(arr))
var obj = {};
console.log(toString.call(obj))
// эту строку var toString = {}.toString;  взял из https://learn.javascript.ru/class-instanceof#sekretnoe-svoystvo-class
```

1. Элемент списка Вопрос как применить toString чтобы получить в консоле объект функция ?

```js
// не одаживал метод и получилось 
var sa = {
  name: 'ad'
}
var d = function g(){};
var u = ['sad', 'sf'];
console.log(toString.call(u))
console.log(toString.call(sa))
console.log(toString.call(d))
```

2. Не одалживал метод и получилось тоже самое ...

Comment: `if (typeof v === "function") {

}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var toString = {}.toString;
var arr = [];
console.log(toString.call(arr));
var obj = {};
console.log(toString.call(obj));
var f1 = function(a) { return a; };
console.log(toString.call(f1));
var f2 = a => a;
console.log(toString.call(f2));
```

Comment: спасибо, я немного изменил вопрос объясните почему получил одинаковый результат ?

Comment: @Leks Во втором примере Вы тоже "одалживаете" - `window.toString`.

Comment: понятно а что лучше использовать ?

Comment: Лучше использовать typeof